# Can Msbuild build a VDD project?

Tags: msbuild

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [create smart device cab through msbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206141/create-smart-device-cab-through-msbuild)

I know MSBUild struggles to build some Setup Projects and the advice here is to use WiX to achieve the goal.

however my google-fu turns up nothing in the way of indicating if Msbuild can cope with VDD projects however from looking at the format of the file I suspect this is a complete no go.

has anyone done something similar? if so by what means did you automatically build these projects

Error Message when attempting to run with Msbuild

“The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One work around I've used to automate Windows Installer project builds on a build server is to fire off a **devenv** commandline to build the installer projects. We since migrated the installers to WIX.

This solution does, however, require Visual Studio to be installed on the build server, and basically starts up the whole VS environment (non visisble though) and asks it to build.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my question may be a duplicate of the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206141/create-smart-device-cab-through-msbuild), so more than happy to have this closed. Installing dev studio on a build agent seems to me to defeat the purpose of having a clean build agent?

Comment: It doesn't defy the purpose but makes the build setup more complex than it has to be. Also, spinning up devenv takes some time. It's unfortunate that MSBuild doesn't support Installer projects directly, but really, there's so much you can't do from those projects anyway, that many people move to WIX when they hit that wall.

Comment: If you want to close, can't you just delete the psot yourself? (but about to VTC)